# Using CONTROL_AF_REGIONS in Camera2 Android

Tags: android, focus, android-camera2, autofocus

So I need to capture multiple pictures using burst capture, one with focus above the center and other with focus below the center. I've been modifying the Camera2Basic code for this. I've implemented burst capture successfully. I've also set CONTROL_AF_REGIONS but it doesn't seem to work.

I've printed the returned focus regions after the capture and they are as expected but the picture itself doesn't show the desired changes, both the images are the same. I've tried to change exposure time before and that works properly so the problem must be in the focus region part.

```java
private void captureStillPicture() {
        try {
            final Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (null == activity || null == mCameraDevice) {
                return;
            }
            CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            CameraCharacteristics in = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId);

            final Rect sensorArraySize = in.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);
            int height = sensorArraySize.height();
            int width = sensorArraySize.width();
            int centerX = sensorArraySize.centerX();
            int centerY = sensorArraySize.centerY();
            System.out.println(centerY);
            System.out.println(centerX);
            MeteringRectangle focusArea1 = new MeteringRectangle(centerX,
                    centerY + centerY - 30 ,
                    150 * 2,
                    150 * 2,
                    1000);
            MeteringRectangle focusArea2 = new MeteringRectangle(centerX,
                    30,
                    150 * 2,
                    150 * 2,
                    1000);

            CaptureRequest.Builder captureStillBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureStillBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

            CaptureRequest.Builder captureStillBuilder2 = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureStillBuilder2.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

            int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

            captureStillBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION,
                    ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            captureStillBuilder2.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION,
                    ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

            CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallback =
                    new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                            MeteringRectangle s = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_REGIONS)[0];
                            System.out.println(Integer.toString(s.getX()) +"-"+ Integer.toString(s.getY()));
                            unlockFocus();
                        }
                    };

            List<CaptureRequest> list = new ArrayList<>();

            captureStillBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
            captureStillBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
            captureStillBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_REGIONS, new MeteringRectangle[]{focusArea1});
            captureStillBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);



            captureStillBuilder2.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
            captureStillBuilder2.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
            captureStillBuilder2.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_REGIONS, new MeteringRectangle[]{focusArea2});
            captureStillBuilder2.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);





            list.add(captureStillBuilder.build());
            list.add(captureStillBuilder2.build());

            mCaptureSession.captureBurst(list, captureCallback, null);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So I've noticed that Camera2Basic calls lockFocus() and the focus is being set there and not being reset after the first capture, can anyone help me remedy this?